# Martial art against verbal hate crime

Tags: training, self-defense

In the wake of rising<sup>1</sup> [hate
crimes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hate_crime) after Brexit and fears of a similar rise after the election of Trump as President of the USA: *How can martial arts help support people who are victim of said crimes?*

Note that this question only focuses on verbal attacks such as racial slurs, sexual explicit comments, and sexual harassment. Physical assault (unarmed or armed with either mêlée weapons or firearms) is out. Of course, the earlier can easily escalate into the latter: losing one's cool is a sure way of escalating this. If it is not yet a fight, how can martial arts help?

As a side note: Checking out with LEO where you live is a good thing. If you
are planning on owning and carrying a lethal weapon, please consult a criminal lawyer first. It might save you jail time.

---

<sub>**1**: Sources for Brexit:
[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-37640982),
[Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/brexit-hate-crime-racism-eu-referendum-poland-islam-more-in-common-a7231836.html), and 
[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2016/sep/07/hate-surged-after-eu-referendum-police-figures-show). Sources for the USA:
[Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-elections/donald-trump-president-supporters-attack-muslims-hijab-hispanics-lgbt-hate-crime-wave-us-election-a7410166.html),
[Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/day-1-trumps-america_us_582497afe4b0cdd5e7e99e86),
[Quartz](http://qz.com/834656/writer-shaun-kings-twitter-account-has-become-a-clearinghouse-for-trump-related-hate-crimes/), and
[Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2016/11/10/the-ku-klux-klan-are-throwing-a-victory-parade-for-donald-trump-6250161/).</sub>

Comment: Fantastic (and important) question, I am often asked things around this topic as an instructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I read it, but *[The Gentle Art of Verbal Self-Defense](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/133203.The_Gentle_Art_of_Verbal_Self_Defense)* is essentially a primer for how to apply martial arts patterns to arguments, ranging from "soft" techniques such as recognizing and redirecting attacks to "hard" techniques such as interjecting more harsh language to shock someone into actually listening. And, much as with martial arts, there are chapters devoted to determining when to fight and when to walk away.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very complex and broad question, so I will add a few general remarks here:

*How can martial arts help support people who are victim of said crimes?*

Increased/Rebuilt confidence

A safe and controlled outlet for emotion/anger

Lasting friendships

Tolerance (not just of pain, but of all life to some degree, walking past the verbal abuse so that it does not become more than that)

---

Obviously these are things that the majority of students will gain from martial arts, it is up to instructors to provide a safe class to allow the student to thrive - taking into consideration any physical or mental conditions suffered by the student.

Comment: It's a community wiki because its essentially a list of expandable points (as you said). I don't really have the vocabulary to take any from bullet to a decent paragraph. When I get worried parents/partners ask about the benefits of taking my class for their loved one those are my go to points (having a female heavy class we have lots of students that have or are suffering verbal/sexual abuse) as a community wiki other users can add their own to this list (there are many more and such a list will never be exhaustive)

Comment: Tolerance is an excellent point, particularly when added to the friendships component. Although not exclusive to martial arts I think that physical type activities which are more confronting have an increased effect. That being getting to know those from other races, cultures, religions etc. The fear of the unknown is normal but getting to know someone and see they are normal or just like you or your uncle Frank helps to eliminate that fear.

Answer (score 2):

Know what your laws are around altercations and what counts as reasonable defense.  Teach them.  Look up some actual, local cases, as what stands on the books may not hold true in court (pay close attention to whether that seems skewed by race or gender, etc. and how that might affect things.) Set up scenarios and play with the idea of verbal intervention and physically interposing yourself between an aggressor and the targeted person.

Consider what you can offer the target to increase their safety - a car ride, and offer to walk them away to another location, willingness to serve as a witness if police have been called.

Consider roleplaying what happens if the target is agitated and angry as well - how to let them know you're on their side BUT that their safety is more important than physical confrontation without silencing them or effectively favoring the verbally violent aggressor.

Train to look for the signs and physical movements of impending violence.  When someone is going to change over from "just words" to action and what are the best strategies around that.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this isn't the answer you want to hear, but what you need to hear.  The martial in martial arts refers to the ability to take a life, and came from ancient times when those skills were needed for life and death in everyday situations.
Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but the issue behind this question is what in NLP is called "framing".  A verbal assault, such as when people intentionally say something to get under your skin, isn't really an assault unless there is intent to commit battery. 
 The thing is your emotions are yours and how you feel is up to you...change your mindset(frame) and feel the way you want to feel.  That means change your internal dialogue and react the way you want to act.
 You might not want think about about what "they" say, so think of your favorite song, or if you want to "verbally" respond, do what Tim Allen did when he was in prison, tell them a joke and change their mindset, this can be done by making fun of yourself with even more exaggeration.

PS- if you might want to apply this knowledge to the news you read as well, some of the news sources you cited are playing politics, and perhaps you should learn about how subversion works in the media.

Comment: False, at least in the US. Assault is anything verbal where the victim feels threatened. Battery is a separate, unnecessary component.

Comment: @JohnP one can only feel threaten if physical harm is likely, physical harm is battery and assault is the threat of battery.  Otherwise, all verbal confrontation would be assault under your made up definition.

Comment: Maybe you should do a little research before you spout off. Assault
Definition

1.  Intentionally putting another person in reasonable apprehension of an imminent harmful or offensive contact.  No intent to cause physical injury needs to exist, and no physical injury needs to result.  So defined in tort law and the criminal statutes of some states.

Comment: @JohnP your first sentence of the definition is correct, and your second is a contradiction of the first. The key word being intent, as intending to cause someone to think your about to harm them without actually touching them.  As for as research goes, I have first hand experience with the subject matter and academic.

Comment: Straight from a law site. Take it up with them. No matter how it is intended, if the recipient chooses to interpret it as threatening, then it is. Much like sexual harassment in the workplace, even if the person offended wasn't in the conversation, if they choose to be offended, the violation has occurred.

Comment: @JohnP sexual harassment is only tort law, not criminal. Anybody can sue anybody for anything. In criminal law, if there isn't a reasonable expectation that a victim would feel threaten by the behavior of the perpetrator then it's not assault, the key word in common law is reasonable. Also, you've proved my point that you have no experience with the subject matter. Perhaps, you should demonstrate your power of criticism on your sources of information when they contradict themselves, meaning if your going to quote a third party then it should be accurate since in essence your vouching for them.

Comment: They are 3 separate definitions. Not more requirements. And depending on state they are tort and criminal. But i thank you for the erroneous assessment of my intelligence.

Comment: @JohnP All three definitions agree on the requirements of intent, which is a requirement for assault.  Eloquently sidestepping your mistake of believing that intention isn't a component of assault proves your intelligence, as well as not admitting to a mistake shows quality of  character.  Thank you for solidifying my point and the exchange of words.

Comment: Intent is the perception of the subject, not the attacker. If they feel threatened, that suffices.

Comment: You are correct Sir, Thank You for your input.  Intent is perceived by the Victim, arresting LEO, Judge, ADA, and the Jury beyond reasonable doubt.  All which requires the Perpetrator to project a threat of immediate physical harm(Battery).  Yet, we've become sidetracked from the OP's question that incorrectly referred to a hate crime as some "verbal attacks such as racial slurs, sexual explicit comments, and sexual harassment", which doesn't even coincide which the OP's link defining a hate crime.  The entire subject matter motivating the OP's question is the result of fake news causing fear.

Answer (score -1):

Martial arts can help many people in troubled times. [Tae Yun Kim](http://www.taeyunkim.com/), who was the first female Taewkondo Grandmaster, teaches about the positivity in life while still teaching people to fend for themselves. She also has some motivational books & videos that talk about using martial arts to help cope with your feelings.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what she said on the subject?